# The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am getting this error when I try to run an ASP.NET application without a web.config file.

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

as I read, we can run .NET applications without web config files, but when I tried it is giving me the error. I am using iis 7 on windows 7 machine.

When I create the application virtual directory inside inetpub/wwwroot it works fine. Why doesn't the other directory location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be a reason:

> If there is no Web.config file in the
>   UNC directory, IIS 7.0 uses the rules
>   that are defined for the parent
>   directory. For the Web content to be
>   served in this scenario, the
>   worker-process identity must have
>   access to the whole content directory.
>   Otherwise, the Web request is
>   rejected.

[Details here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934515/en-us).

Answer (score 22):

One reason could be the version of .NET framework (on IIS or application pool level) is different from the application one.

Another reason could be if there are modules used in your `web.config` which the current configuration of IIS doesn't *recognize*. E.g. `URL rewrite` or other optional modules, which you have to explicitly enable before using.

Comment: +1 The second reason was my problem: I was using URL rewrite for development.

Comment: Plus one for Url Rewrite

Answer (score 2):

You need to set permission for your Website folder or copy them to `wwwroot` folder.

If you choose to set permission, there are two ways:

- Right click on Your Website folder, or
- Right click to Your Website in IIS

Then select *Edit permission* and *Add a permission* (IUSR - default iis user)

Answer (score 0):

While building a web API using .NET Core 5, I encountered this error due to my failure to install the appropriate .NET Core hosting bundle on IIS. However, after installing the correct version of the hosting bundle, the error was resolved.