# Virtual directory point to another server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I am working on a Website, hosted on a IIS server 7.5.
I created one virtual directory and pointing to another server's folder for accessing locally hosted pages from another local server.
But it is not displaying page and giving error :

> "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to permissions or trust issues. Have you verified that you have set the correct rights. You may use the caspol.exe to modify the security policy. Also, it might be useful to take a look at the following link to configure content served from a remote server.
http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/aspnet-20-35-shared-hosting-configuration

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Web.config file in the UNC directory, IIS 7.0 uses the rules that are defined for the parent directory. For the Web content to be served in this scenario, the worker-process identity must have access to the whole content directory. Otherwise, the Web request is rejected.

Used From : [The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596392/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for)

Comment: UNC directory is also having web.config file as this one also a separate web application and locally hosted on different server